# Raise Exception from response message

Tags: python-3.x

How to raise an exception from the response message e.g {'status': "insufficient credit"}

```
                try:
                    new_order = api.request(r)
                except as                       :
                    print(new_order['status'])
                else:
                    print(new_order)
```

The response message has different key/values when successful/unsuccessful.

Comment: What are the known values for `'status'` that would be considered successes? You could use a simple if else statement and raise some sort of exception if the status is considered 'unsuccessful'.

Comment: the response is {'status': "insufficient credit"} and when it's successful its a completely different dict with different key/values.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to know what `api.request` is to answer your question exactly.

Without know what it is, I would suggest using [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) with the error, which is in the standard python library.

for example:

```
import traceback
try:
    new_order = api.request(r)
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
    traceback.print_exc()

else:
    print(new_order)
```

Also, if `api.request` is raising an exception, it wouldn't be related to any "status message" they send.  If they are telling you about the error, then `api.result` will likely return an object/list with the status code and/or error message in it, and not raise an exception on your server (which I don't think is possible for them to do).

Think of it like this: your server side code executes `api.request`, which is probably either a GET or POST request to the api's server.  If there was an error in your request, they will send you a message saying what the problem is (I assume).  No where in this process will an exception be *raised*.

If the request is sent to their server, there *shouldn't* be any exceptions raised on your server.

an exception is raised when you call `raise 'some exception here'`, or when there is a syntax error/other serious error.  In either case, your code execution is immediately stopped, and your server would respond to your client with a [500 internal service error](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html).

Comment: It sounds like I need an additional nested if statement in my else statement. This isnt an exception but a response that is affecting my code under the else statement.